# How to filter data using checkbox if checkbox are dependent?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

How can I filter data using checkbox so when I click on state then state data must be displayed. Since state and city are dependent a click on city checkbox city data must be displayed.

index.php

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <form method="get" id="search_form">

    <div class="row">
      <div id="find"></div>
      <!-- sidebar -->
      <aside class="col-lg-3 col-md-4">

        <div class="panel list">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#panelOne" aria-expanded="true">State</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body collapse in" id="panelOne">
            <div id="state-filter">
              <ul class="list-group" id="scroll">
               <?php
                    include('config.php');
                    $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM indian_statemaster ORDER BY statename ASC");
                    $rowCount = $query->num_rows;
                ?>
                <?php

                    if($rowCount > 0)
                    {
                   $n = 1;
                   while($row = $query->fetch_assoc())
                       { ?>

                <li class="list-group-item">
                  <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                      <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row['stateid']; ?> " name=="state[]" id="state<?php echo $n++ ; ?>" class="sort_rang">&nbsp;&nbsp;
                      <?php echo $row[ 'statename']; ?>
                    </label>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <?php }}?>
                <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $n ;?> " id="num">
                </label>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel list">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#panelTwo" aria-expanded="true">City</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body collapse in" id="panelTwo">
            <div id="city-filter">
              <ul class="list-group" id="scroll">
                <li class="list-group-item">
                  <div class="checkbox" style="margin-left: 20px;">
                    <span class="sort_rang" id="city"></span>
                  </div>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </aside>

    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

ajaxData.php

```html
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var id = document.getElementById("num").value;

    for (i = 1; i <= id; i++) {
      $('#state' + i).click(function() {
        var stateID = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function() {
          return $(this).val();
        }).get().join();

        if (stateID) {
          $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'ajaxData.php',
            data: 'stateid=' + stateID,
            success: function(html) {
              $('#city').html(html);
            }
          });
        }
      });
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: ajaxData.php has javascript in it? and you are calling the same 'ajaxData.php' inside that script in your ajax call?

Comment: Yes, that's not AJAX.  Ajax means the javascript of the webpage (this is client side) fetches data on a server.  So 'ajaxData.php' contains data,  Not javascript.  And don't send Ajax requests in a for-loop, you can do all of this in one request.